# Simplifying ItemTemplate output of `GridView` to regular <td>

Tags: asp.net, gridview, templatefield

I'm using a `TemplateField` for a column because I need the `HeaderTemplate`. However, the `ItemTemplate` renders the content of a cell as an `<asp:Label>` and the output looks like this:

```
<td><span>data</span></td>
```

Is there any way to make the `ItemTemplate` just render the content of the cell so that the output will look like this:

```
<td>data</td>
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built in templates that are autogenerated will always use a `Label` for simplicity because they assume you might want to do formatting.  If you want to just get basic HTML out switch it to use a `Literal` instead of a `Label`.  A `Literal` acts almost the same as a `Label` with no formatting so there is no `span` tags.  Change your `TemplateField` to the following:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="ltTestItem" runat="server" Text="Test" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

It will produce:

```
<td>Test</td>
```

You can do the binding however you want by replacing the `Text` value with `Eval("yourField")` or by implementing the OnDataBinding for the control and manipulate it however you like.